# Maximizing the logarithm of a Poisson function in respect to its parameter by setting the derivative to zero

Tags: derivatives, logarithms, poisson-distribution, maximum-likelihood

In solving a Maximum Likelihood problem, I am trying to maximize the Poisson function in respect to its parameter x.  Instead, I opt to maximize the logarithm of the function.  The derivations have as follows.  k = 0, 1, 2 ...

[derivation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdHDx.png)

I am puzzled as k is non-negative.

Could you advise me where I err and how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac{d}{dx}(\log(e^{-x}))$ is $-1$, not $x$. If you want to do chain rule, the computation is $\frac{1}{e^{-x}} \cdot (-e^{-x}) = -1$.

---

However, it is much easier to to take logarithms before differentiating.
$$\frac{d}{dx} \log \frac{x^k e^{-x}}{k!} = \frac{d}{dx}\left(k \log(x) -
 x - \log(k!)\right) = \frac{k}{x} - 1.$$

Setting this to zero gives $x=k$.